# In PyQt, how can I cycle through multiple copies of a widget and have each of them remember their state?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm building a program where a user can interact with a `pyqtgraph` `ImageView` (e.g. place markers, change brightness and contrast). I want to be able to cycle through different images, but have each image remember its state with the markers etc. I feel like the most appropriate solution would be to create a copy of the `ImageView` for each image and show the current one and hide the other ones. What would be the best way to do that and would that even be a good idea?

My naive approach was placing an empty widget in Qt Designer (called `graphWidget`), promoting that to the `ImageView` class, and then in the program:

```
graphWidget_backup = self.graphWidget
secondWidget = pg.ImageView()
secondWidget.setImage(np.random.rand(256,256))

self.graphWidget = secondWidget
```

But with that, nothing happens.

Of course I could also just save the image data and all other changes manually and set them on the `ImageView`, but that feels less elegant and "object oriented".

Comment: Overwriting an instance attribute is useless for this: it's just a reference, it doesn't make the widget magically appear in place of another. A possible solution would be to use QStackedWidget (or QTabWidget) with all promoted widgets in Designer, and finally set the images by code. That is, unless you want to add the graph widgets *dynamically*.

Comment: @musicamante Indeed I want to add the widgets dynamically.